allow nestjs application to start even if MongoDB is temporarily unavailable
i am using nestjs with mongo db as secondary db, the issue is that if the mongo is temp unavailable, the nestjs app can not start and can not use other module. So have any way or config that still allow the nestjs app can continue without nest/mongo module ?
Allow nestjs app can start if mongo serve is temp unavailable.
